# angular firestore insufficient permission

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

in my angular app used firebase as db, connected the app with firebase with angular/fire in module.ts and the environment of firebase is done, its working fine for login and signup, when user is signed in the firestore data is not fetching, throws error in console and when the firestore rules is changed to open its working fine , not working when rules is restricted to authenticated users.

```
> Error: core.js:6185 ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient
> permissions.
>     at new e (prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:188)
>     at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10416
>     at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10417
>     at e.onMessage (prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10439)
>     at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10356
>     at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10387
>     at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:15194
>     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
>     at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
>     at zone-evergreen.js:857
```

this is my firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '1';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Angular code:

```js
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth' 
constructor(private Auth:AngularFireAuth) {}

login(AuthData:AuthData) {
    this.Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(AuthData.email,AuthData.password)
    .then().catch(error => {
        this.uiSer.snackBar(error.message,null,3000);
    })
}
```

data fetch code: the call to fetchsendExercise() is done on required component and all other required are imported , they're working fine.

```
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
    constructor(private db:AngularFirestore){}

   fetchsendExercise(){   
        
      this.db.collection('exercises').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(docArray=>{            
                    return docArray.map(doc=>{return{
            id:doc.payload.doc.id,
            name:doc.payload.doc.data().name,
            duration:doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
            calories:doc.payload.doc.data().calories

        }
    })         
}))
.subscribe((data:Exercise[])=>{this.availableExercise=data
        this.fetchExercise.next([...this.availableExercise])
        this.ui.exerciseLoading.next(false);
        })
        
    }
```

Comment: The code you shared so far does not read any data from Firestore, so can't be causing this error. Most likely you're attaching an observer to Firestore before the `login` completes.

Comment: i made the read and write on separate service , I'll share it on edit

Comment: How are you ensuring that the user is signed in before you subscribe to `snapshotChanges()`? Given that your security rules enforce that requirement, your code should do the same.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yup thats correct and i'm subscribing to those only if user is authenticated successfully, still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to my problem, it's error from the latest firebase, after rolledback to previous version its working fine, run `npm i firebase@8.6.1`

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for posting this fix. I have been chasing this around for a day...